# Haskell: Constraining function pattern variables with |

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

While I was browsing Persistent source code, I came across this function below in file [Quasi.hs](https://github.com/yesodweb/persistent/blob/v2.5.1.4/persistent/Database/Persist/Quasi.hs) (I referred to a tag with the relevant code equal to the one in the present state in master branch, since the tag's code is more unlikely to change).
In the line `takeConstraint ps tableName defs (n:rest) | not (T.null n) && isUpper (T.head n) = takeConstraint'` there is this pipe (|) character following the argument pattern.
Is the expression between `|` and `=` like a constraint to arguments in the pattern? So do I interpret this `|` as the same symbol in Math, i.e. *"such that"*?

```
takeConstraint :: PersistSettings
          -> Text
          -> [FieldDef]
          -> [Text]
          -> (Maybe FieldDef, Maybe CompositeDef, Maybe UniqueDef, Maybe UnboundForeignDef)
takeConstraint ps tableName defs (n:rest) | not (T.null n) && isUpper (T.head n) = takeConstraint' --- <<<<< This line
    where
      takeConstraint' 
            | n == "Unique"  = (Nothing, Nothing, Just $ takeUniq ps tableName defs rest, Nothing)
            | n == "Foreign" = (Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Just $ takeForeign ps tableName defs rest)
            | n == "Primary" = (Nothing, Just $ takeComposite defs rest, Nothing, Nothing)
            | n == "Id"      = (Just $ takeId ps tableName (n:rest), Nothing, Nothing, Nothing)
            | otherwise      = (Nothing, Nothing, Just $ takeUniq ps "" defs (n:rest), Nothing) -- retain compatibility with original unique constraint
takeConstraint _ _ _ _ = (Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it means precisely “*such that*”. These are [guards](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions), very common in Haskell (generally preferred to the equivalent `if` `then` `else` expression).

```
f x
 | x > 2      = a
 | x < -4     = b
 | otherwise  = x
```

is equivalent to

```
f x = if x > 2 then a
               else if x < -4 then b
                              else x
```

IMO that specific example would actually have better been written with neither `if` nor guards, but

```
    takeConstraint' = case n of
        "Unique"  -> (Nothing, Nothing, Just $ takeUniq ps tableName defs rest, Nothing)
        "Foreign" -> (Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Just $ takeForeign ps tableName defs rest)
        "Primary" -> (Nothing, Just $ takeComposite defs rest, Nothing, Nothing)
        "Id"      -> (Just $ takeId ps tableName (n:rest), Nothing, Nothing, Nothing)
        _         -> (Nothing, Nothing, Just $ takeUniq ps "" defs (n:rest), Nothing)
```

Comment: The `case` looks better for me as well.

Comment: I agree, cramming a whole function block between after the guard was a bit misleading, I thought it was a completely novel feature from Haskell.